# php ajax search does not display results

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make a php ajax search for the articles posted in database, but it gives me only : No results message. I've tested the connection to database and the  select query, and it works.
This is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('dbconn.php');
$s = $_GET["s"];
$livesearch = '';
if (strlen($s) > 0)

{
    $result = mysql_query("select * from articles where art_sts='1' ORDER BY title"); 
    if ($result != FALSE)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            if (stristr($row['title'], $s))
            {
                if ($livesearch == '')
                {
                    $livesearch = '<a href="upload_pdf/'.$row["fisier"].'?id='.$row["id"].' "> '.htmlentities($row["title"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</a>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

if ($livesearch == '')
{
    $respond="No results...";
}
else
{
$respond = $livesearch;
}
echo $respond;
?>
```

Comment: `$result` is a resource. You'll need to fetch data from `$result`. Something like this : `while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... }`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `mysql_` functions on new development. They're deprecated. You might as well upgrade to PDO now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent actually fetched the data that you are trying to output. You will need to add something like this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if (stristr($row['title'], $s))
        {
            if ($livesearch == '')
            {
                $livesearch = '<a href="upload_pdf/'.$row["fisier"].'?id='.$row["id"].' "> '.htmlentities($row["title"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</a>';
            }
        }
}
```